# Excel: transpose rows to columns and merge

Tags: excel

I would like to present some data in Excel in a table. I have a sheet with three columns: date, time_spent and user_id. Every row is a data record. I want a table with a column for every date and every value with time spent below the date.

Using the transpose function under paste special I get this:
[image: Using the transpose function under paste special I get this:]

However I would like only one column per unique date, so the amount of columns decrease like this:

[image]

Does someone know how to do this?\
I have more than 10000 rows, so manually is too much effort...

Using Pivot Tables as Tim Biegeleisen suggested I cannot get what I want either, I'm not an expierenced user of Pivot Tables so probably I'm doing something wrong:

[image]

[Excel file as shown in above picture](http://robabeling.com/download/stackoverflow.xlsx)

Comment: Do you want to _aggregate_ the `time_spent` for each date?  If so, then you might want to look into using pivot tables.

Comment: @pnuts Could you maybe show what you mean with that using my Excel file [link](http://robabeling.com/download/stackoverflow.xlsx)

Comment: Excel link in your question is dead...

Comment: It should work now, accidently added a / at the end, thanks for noticing

Comment: You can use the pivot table on your original table, but the dates need to be "real dates" and not text.  You drag dates to the column area, and time spent to the values area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Advanced filter dates to unique values in a new column
2. Copy and transpose them to make your column titles
3. Insert a new column B with the formula `=TEXT(A2,"yyyyddmmm")&COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)` and fill down
4. Below your new column headers put in the formula `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TEXT(H$1,"yyyyddmmm")&ROW()-1,$B$2:$C$8,2,FALSE),"")` and fill down and across. You will need to fill it down to cover the maximum number of instances of each date.
5. Adding a sumif to this table and your initial table would be a good way to check you got everything.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, this solution did the job. I had to change `"yyyyddmmm"` to `"jjjjddmmm"` due to some locale settings (dutch), but then it worked perfectly!

Comment: Glad that it worked. Also know you should be able to use any order of the date components, I just chose that order so the count number was easy to see.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of using a Pivot Table as suggested by Tim above in the comments, but you must use it on your original, non-transposed data:  (and note which parameters go to which areas.

[image]

A disadvantage of the Pivot table is that the column headers are text strings and not dates.  If your version of Excel is 2010+, you can use `Power Pivot` or `Get and Transform` to do a better job:

- Open the Query Editor, change the format of the Date column, and Pivot the column:

[image]

Then Save the results:

[image]

Comment: This is almost what I want. Now there are no 'duplicate' columns anymore in my table but the time_spent is summed up for every date. Is it also possible to just display all values for dates with multiple times_spent top-down below that date?

Comment: By the way, I am not having issues with dates being formatted as strings rather than 'real dates' in both the data cells and the pivot table headers (using Excel 2016), so that's a good thing :)

Comment: @robabeling move time_spent from Values to Columns below date

Comment: @robabeling For that type of result, I would suggest trying `atclaus` solution, or developing a VBA solution.